# Embedding fonts in Editable PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, font-embedding

I have produced a pdf document with Latex (a survey), then I used Foxit PhantomPDF to make that PDF editable (so that I can send it via mail).
To do that I used the 'Form': 'Text Fiel'; and I choose a particular font in the Properties.
I sent the file to a friend and he completed the survey, but the font that he saw was different from mine. What can I do so that everyone sees the font that I want?

(The font that I choose is embeddable, and I tried to convert the pdf to ps and then with adobe Distiller 7.0 convert it to pdf embedding the font. These 2 sistems didn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomPDF doesn't embed fonts for use in form filling... at least not correctly... and none that I've ever tried. Use Adobe Acrobat DC to add the fields. When you select a font that **can be** embedded, it **will be** embedded so that recipients of the form will be able to edit the fields using the same font that you specified. Of course, they also need to use a PDF viewer that is capable of using the embedded font you specified. Many... probably most... won't... but Adobe Reader does.